# Bull queue not connecting with docker redis service. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, nestjs, bull-queue

I am trying to establish a redis connection in nestjs via docker. I am using ioredis to connect to the redis but when I start my nest application I am keep on getting ECONNREFUSED. It also looks like the bull queue is also not establishing the connection with redis.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
```

I have went through many solutions provided but nothing seems to be working.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [redisConfig],
    }),
    BullModule.registerQueueAsync({
      name: 'jobs',
      imports: [ConfigModule.forFeature(bullQueueConfig)],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        redis: {
          ...configService.get('bullQueue'),
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [ConfigurationController],
  providers: [ConfigurationService, ConfigurationRepository],
  exports: [ConfigurationService],
})
export class ConfigurationModule {}
```

bull queue config

```
export default registerAs('bullQueue', () => {
  const redisURL =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local'
      ? {
          host: process.env.BULL_QUEUE_REDIS_HOST,
          port: parseInt(process.env.BULL_QUEUE_REDIS_PORT ?? '6379'),
        }
      : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(process.env.REDIS_URL));

  const env = {
    ...redisURL,
  };

  return env;
```

I get ECONNREFUSED error after the configuration module initialized.

In my .ts file

```
this.redisClient = new Redis({
        ...newRedisObj,
      });
```

newRedisObj also holds the correct values

```
{host: 'redis', port: 6379}
```

Redis config

```
export default registerAs('redis', () => {
  const redisURL =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local'
      ? {
          host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
          port: parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT ?? '6379'),
        }
      : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(process.env.REDIS_URL));

  const env = {
    ...redisURL,
    
  };

  return env;
```

The config is returning the correct json with

```
{host: 'redis', port: 6379}
```

But it is still try to connect with 127.0.0.1:6379 and hence ECONNREFUSED.

The docker-compose has also the correct setup

```
redis:
    container_name: redis_container
    image: "bitnami/redis"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - "redis_data:/bitnami/redis/data"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this setup for redis and redis commander. Try it with docker compose -up

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redis-data:/data'

  redis-commander:
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    depends_on:
      - redis

volumes:
  redis-data:
    external: false
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I have tried with the above setup but still the same error
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Comment: maybe try register.async?

Answer (score 0):

Iguess it's because you have to use:

```
export default registerAs('redis', () => {
  const redisURL =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local'
      ? {
          host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
          port: parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT ?? '6379'),
        }
      : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(process.env.REDIS_URL));

 // look here is surrounded by redis prop
  const env = {
    redis:...redisURL,
    
  };

  return env;
```

[nestjs bull screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX6WW.png)